# Google custom search on the whole web and limitations (gizoogle)

Tags: javascript, node.js, search-engine, google-search-api, google-custom-search

I am working on a search engine that needs to have access to results from google. Here are my options:

- Using the custom search API
- Using a proxy to make my server send searches and return the data

I am not sure about some things though:

Is the custom search API limited? I may need a really big amount of queries, so if the use is limited it will be a problem.

Is it "authorized" to use a proxy in node that would send search queries to google and intercept the result to show to my users? If I do so, wouldn't I run to some limitations?

The inspiration here is [gizoogle](http://gizoogle.net) which managed to plug into google API (they have the same results as google) while still not using custom search (custom search displays adds, and there aren't any on this website). So I assume they have some sort of proxy, but how come google let them run those queries?

Edit: It turns out that the custom search API is also limited. So, how did gizoogle do ?

Comment: Google has strict limits for how you can access their search, for good reason.  If you want to automatically perform high volumes of searches, you're going to have to pay them, probably a fair amount, for that privilege

Comment: says "Bing" on my search results on gizoogle... so, that's how they did it; they didn't, they used bing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok here is how I solved this problem:

It turns out that google has a lost API (probably deprecated so be aware of this) for client-side ajax search. It looks like that:

`http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=test&rsz=large`

Just go to [that url](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=test&rsz=large) to see what results it gives.

So basically here is the process:

- The user types a search
- It is sent to your server in ajax
- The server might modify the search depending on your application (filtering forbidden words or whatever)
- Your server polls the ajax web service from google - don't forget to add the `get`parameter `userIp` which is needed to avoid limitations (google limits incoming queries from each user, so your server has to tell google that it is making a request on behalf of this `userIp`
- You send back the results to the client, and then use javascript to display them

The only drawback is that the search must be made in ajax, meaning that the page is empty at load and filled later. But you could actually use get parameters in URL to preload the search and fill the page before sending it to the client though.

Answer (score 2):

Google Custom Search (GCS) has a [free mode and a paid ("enterprise") mode](https://www.google.com/cse/compare).

Both modes are regulated by a terms of service ([Custom Search Terms of Service](https://cloud.google.com/console/tos?id=customsearch)) - make sure you read carefully.

From what I understand, you can use the free mode and search as much as you'd like.  Because google is returning the results, they also return ads, so they get paid that way.

The paid mode gives you access to the API, and let's you turn off the ads and do other things. But [it comes at a cost](http://www.google.com/enterprise/search/products/gss.html#pricing_content).

I've been combing through the documentation and terms and the like -- it's really not Google's best effort.  But if you are using it exactly as they describe, it's pretty standard, really.

Comment: Yes that's what I've been reading. Although there is no clear statement that the free version is unlimited. But I hope so. Good answer anyway

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your project size and funds available but you could get a GSA http://www.google.com/enterprise/search/products/gsa.html

The Dr Oz webite uses this to index and pull in results from partnered sites, you would have the ability to include Google results as well. Highly customizable with the works from source weight ranking, filtering options to custom output.